# how i get information from the indicator signs I used in mql4

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mql5

I'm using an indicator in mql4 that gives me a sign to buy or sell,
How can I write an expert and read it and perform my operations whenever this symbol is added?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                      ProjectName |
//|                                      Copyright 2020, CompanyName |
//|                                       http://www.companyname.net |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#include<Trade\Trade.mqh>
CTrade trade;
int direction=1;
input double               ATRProfit=2;
input double               ATRLoss=1;
input int                  TotalTrade=1;
input double               Risk=0.01;
input double               DecreaseRisk=0;
input uint                 MaximumConsecutiveWins=4;
input double               BaseConsecutiveWins=1.96;
input int                  MinimumConsecutiveWinsToResetRisk=2;
input bool                 ExponentialGrowthRisk=true;
input bool                 ChangeDirection=true;
input bool                 Trailing=true;
input bool                 ExitIndicator=true;
input bool                 ExitInProfit=true;
input double               SecureTheDeal=1;
input double               SecureTheProfit=0;
input group "ATR"
input ENUM_TIMEFRAMES      ATR_Period=PERIOD_CURRENT;
input int                  ATR_ma_Period=14;
input group "ADX"
input ENUM_TIMEFRAMES      ADX_Period=PERIOD_CURRENT;
input int                  adx_Period=14;
input group "MAADX"
input ENUM_TIMEFRAMES      MAADX_Period=PERIOD_CURRENT;
input int                  adx_ma_Period=10;
input int                  adx_ma_shift=0;
input ENUM_MA_METHOD       adx_ma_method=MODE_SMA;
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int ATR=iATR(_Symbol,ATR_Period,ATR_ma_Period);
int ADX=iADX(_Symbol,ADX_Period,adx_Period);
int MAADX=iMA(_Symbol,MAADX_Period,adx_ma_Period,adx_ma_shift,adx_ma_method,ADX);
void OnTick()
{
 double ATRA[];
 double MAIN_LINEA[];
 double PLUSDI_LINEA[];
 double MINUSDI_LINEA[];
 double MAADXA[];

 ArraySetAsSeries(ATRA,true);
 ArraySetAsSeries(MAIN_LINEA,true);
 ArraySetAsSeries(PLUSDI_LINEA,true);
 ArraySetAsSeries(MINUSDI_LINEA,true);
 ArraySetAsSeries(MAADXA,true);

 CopyBuffer(ATR,0,0,10,ATRA);
 CopyBuffer(ADX,0,0,10,MAIN_LINEA);
 CopyBuffer(ADX,1,0,10,PLUSDI_LINEA);
 CopyBuffer(ADX,2,0,10,MINUSDI_LINEA);
 CopyBuffer(MAADX,0,0,10,MAADXA);

 string signal;
 string CloseAllBUY;
 string CloseAllSELL;
 static double LastTrailingBuy;
 static double LastTrailingSell;
 double Ask=NormalizeDouble(SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_ASK),_Digits);
 double Bid=NormalizeDouble(SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_BID),_Digits);
 bool x=false;
 if(ConsecutiveTrade()<MinimumConsecutiveWinsToResetRisk)
  x=true;
 double risk=Risk*pow(DecreaseRisk,x)*pow(pow(ConsecutiveTrade()-MinimumConsecutiveWinsToResetRisk,1-ExponentialGrowthRisk)*pow(pow(BaseConsecutiveWins,ExponentialGrowthRisk),ConsecutiveTrade()-MinimumConsecutiveWinsToResetRisk),1-x);
 double PipValue=(((SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_TRADE_TICK_VALUE))*_Point)/(SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_TRADE_TICK_SIZE)));
 double lot=floor((risk*AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_BALANCE)/(PipValue*ATRA[0]*ATRLoss/_Point))*100)/100;
 if(lot==0)
  lot=0.01;
 Comment("Best BaseConsecutiveWins",100*(1-(1/(1+0.01*(ATRProfit/ATRLoss)))));

 if(PLUSDI_LINEA[1]>MINUSDI_LINEA[1] && PLUSDI_LINEA[2]<MINUSDI_LINEA[2] && MAIN_LINEA[1]>MAADXA[1])
  signal="buy";
 if(PLUSDI_LINEA[1]<MINUSDI_LINEA[1] && PLUSDI_LINEA[2]>MINUSDI_LINEA[2] && MAIN_LINEA[1]>MAADXA[1])
  signal="sell";

 while(ChangeDirection==true && LastProfit()<0 && PositionsForThisCurrencyPair()<TotalTrade && (signal=="buy" || signal=="sell"))
 {
  if(direction==2)
   direction=0;
  direction++;
  break;
 }

 if(direction==1)
 {
  if(signal=="buy" && CloseAllBUY!="Exit" && PositionsForThisCurrencyPair()<TotalTrade)
  {
   trade.Buy(lot,NULL,Ask,(Ask-ATRA[0]*ATRLoss),(Ask+ATRA[0]*ATRProfit),direction);
   LastTrailingBuy=0;
  }
  if(signal=="sell" && CloseAllSELL!="Exit" && PositionsForThisCurrencyPair()<TotalTrade)
  {
   trade.Sell(lot,NULL,Bid,(Bid+ATRA[0]*ATRLoss),(Bid-ATRA[0]*ATRProfit),direction);
   LastTrailingSell=1000;
  }
 }

 if(direction==2)
 {
  if(signal=="buy" && CloseAllBUY!="Exit" && PositionsForThisCurrencyPair()<TotalTrade)
  {
   trade.Sell(lot,NULL,Bid,(Bid+ATRA[0]*ATRLoss),(Bid-ATRA[0]*ATRProfit),direction);
   LastTrailingSell=1000;
  }
  if(signal=="sell" && CloseAllSELL!="Exit" && PositionsForThisCurrencyPair()<TotalTrade)
  {
   trade.Buy(lot,NULL,Ask,(Ask-ATRA[0]*ATRLoss),(Ask+ATRA[0]*ATRProfit),direction);
   LastTrailingBuy=0;
  }
 }

 if(ExitIndicator==true && ExitInProfit*PositionGetDouble(POSITION_PROFIT)>=0)
 {
  if(PLUSDI_LINEA[1]<MINUSDI_LINEA[1])
  {
   CloseAllBUYPositions();
   CloseAllBUY="Exit";
  }
  if(PLUSDI_LINEA[1]>MINUSDI_LINEA[1])
  {
   CloseAllSELLPositions();
   CloseAllSELL="Exit";
  }
 }

 if(Trailing==true)
 {
  double TrailingBuy=(Ask-ATRA[0]*ATRLoss);
  if(TrailingBuy<Bid && TrailingBuy>LastTrailingBuy)
  {
   CheckTrailingBuy(Ask,TrailingBuy);
   LastTrailingBuy=TrailingBuy;
  }
  double TrailingSell=(Bid+ATRA[0]*ATRLoss);
  if(TrailingSell>Ask && TrailingSell<LastTrailingSell)
  {
   CheckTrailingSell(Bid,TrailingSell);
   LastTrailingSell=TrailingSell;
  }
 }

 CheckSecureTheDeal();
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void CloseAllBUYPositions()
{
 for(int i=PositionsTotal()-1; i>=0; i--)
  if(_Symbol==PositionGetSymbol(i))
   if(PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE)==POSITION_TYPE_BUY)
    trade.PositionClose(PositionGetTicket(i));
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void CloseAllSELLPositions()
{
 for(int i=PositionsTotal()-1; i>=0; i--)
  if(_Symbol==PositionGetSymbol(i))
   if(PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE)==POSITION_TYPE_SELL)
    trade.PositionClose(PositionGetTicket(i));
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void CheckTrailingBuy(double Ask,double TrailingBuy)
{
 for(int i=PositionsTotal()-1; i>=0; i--)
  if(_Symbol==PositionGetSymbol(i))
  {
   double SL=PositionGetDouble(POSITION_SL);
   if((SL<TrailingBuy)||(SL==0))
    trade.PositionModify(PositionGetTicket(i),TrailingBuy,PositionGetDouble(POSITION_TP));
  }
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void CheckTrailingSell(double Bid,double TrailingSell)
{
 for(int i=PositionsTotal()-1; i>=0; i--)
  if(_Symbol==PositionGetSymbol(i))
  {
   double SL=PositionGetDouble(POSITION_SL);
   if((SL>TrailingSell)||(SL==0))
    trade.PositionModify(PositionGetTicket(i),TrailingSell,PositionGetDouble(POSITION_TP));
  }
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void CheckSecureTheDeal()
{
 for(int i=PositionsTotal()-1; i>=0; i--)
  if(_Symbol==PositionGetSymbol(i))
  {
   double TP=PositionGetDouble(POSITION_TP);
   double PriceCurrent=PositionGetDouble(POSITION_PRICE_CURRENT);
   double PriceOpen=PositionGetDouble(POSITION_PRICE_OPEN);
   if((PriceCurrent>PriceOpen+((TP-PriceOpen)*SecureTheDeal) && PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE)==POSITION_TYPE_BUY)
      || (PriceCurrent<PriceOpen+((TP-PriceOpen)*SecureTheDeal) && PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE)==POSITION_TYPE_SELL))
    trade.PositionModify(PositionGetTicket(i),PriceOpen+((TP-PriceOpen)*SecureTheProfit),TP);
  }
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
double LastProfit()
{
 double LastProfit=0;
 HistorySelect(0,TimeCurrent());
 for(int i=0; i<HistoryDealsTotal()-PositionsTotal(); i++)
  LastProfit=HistoryDealGetDouble(HistoryDealGetTicket(i),DEAL_PROFIT);
 return LastProfit;
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int ConsecutiveTrade()
{
 double ConsecutiveWins=0;
 for(int i=HistoryDealsTotal()-PositionsTotal(); i>=0; i--)
 {
  if(HistoryDealGetDouble(HistoryDealGetTicket(i),DEAL_PROFIT)<0 || ConsecutiveWins>MaximumConsecutiveWins+MinimumConsecutiveWinsToResetRisk)
   break;
  ConsecutiveWins+=0.5;
 }
 double ConsecutiveLosses=0;
 for(int i=HistoryDealsTotal()-PositionsTotal(); i>=0; i--)
 {
  if(HistoryDealGetDouble(HistoryDealGetTicket(i),DEAL_PROFIT)>0)
   break;
  ConsecutiveLosses+=0.5;
 }
 return ConsecutiveWins-ConsecutiveLosses;
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int PositionsForThisCurrencyPair()
{
 int PositionsForThisCurrencyPair=0;
 for(int i=PositionsTotal(); i>=0; i--)
  if(_Symbol==PositionGetSymbol(i))
   PositionsForThisCurrencyPair++;
 return PositionsForThisCurrencyPair;
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use global variables to read/write signal information between EA and indicator

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.